# Using .hide() and .show() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program I have several very similar drop-down menus all with the same name (foo in the following example). On change they hide or show a nearby div tag depending on whether or not "ON" was selected.

```
$('.togClass').hide();
        $('[name*="foo"]').change(function(){
            if ($('[value="ON"]').is(':selected')) {
                $('.togClass').show('blind', 1000);
            } else {
                $('.togClass').hide(1000);
            } 
        });
```

As it is, all of the div tags with class "togClass" toggle when *any* of the drop down menus choose "ON", is there a way that I can choose to show/hide only the *nearby* div to the drop-down that chooses "ON"(they are nested in the same div)? I don't want to write a copy of this function for every div I want to hide.

Here is how it works in the HTML:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
    <option value="ON">ON</option>
</select><br/>
<div class="togClass">
    //Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: This would be far easier to answer if you could post your html (or, at least a snippet) or even a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the same.

Comment: I added the relevant HTML I hope that helps!

Comment: I suggest using more specific selectors - it would be easier to human eye to read, and jquery to faster locate elements. For example - $(".class") - not so good, $("div.class") - much better. $('[name*="foo"]') - $('select[name*="foo"]'). The more ambiguous the selectors are, the more time it takes jquery to locate the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you can. Check out the jquery doc about traversing: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ It has a lot of great examples.

For your problem the solution could be: [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('div.togClass').hide();
$('select[name*="foo"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "ON") {
     $(this).siblings('div.togClass').show('blind', 1000);
  } else {
      $(this).siblings('div.togClass').hide(1000);
  } 
});
```

Comment: In your example, what precisely is the $('this') referring to? The link you shared on traversal was helpful, but I'm having trouble knowing where I'm starting from.

Comment: $(this) is referring to the element that triggered 'change', that belongs to $('[name*="foo"]') elements. Take a look at this [link](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) it explains the use of `this`

Comment: I've tried using .closest as you suggested, as well as .next and .parent().next but it's still not working. Looking at the HTML I added above can you make a suggestion?

Comment: I edited my code, try it. I noticed you had some errors in code - $('[value="ON"]').is(':selected') - this line means that you are selecting ALL elements with `value` attribute and checking if it is selected. Instead, you have to check only the sender(the one that triggered 'change' event) elements value like this: `$(this).val() == "ON"`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I still cannot get it to work though. The problem is in this line: $(this).closest('div.togClass').show('blind', 1000); but for the life of me I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I wish I could up vote this answer a few more times. Siblings works great, I finally figured out that .nextAll().filter(...) worked too, but siblings is even better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell us a bit more about what "nearby" means. But it appears that the fundamental piece you're missing is the use of `$(this)` within the `change` function. Instead of identifying *any* `.togClass` item, you want to identify a *specific* one relative to `$(this)` -- the element being changed.

Here's one way to do it with the assumption that the associated `.togClass` div is the next one to be found in the DOM.

```
$('[name*="foo"]').change(function(){
  if( $(this).is(':selected') ) { // relative to the selected item
    $(this).next('.togClass').show('blind',1000);
  } else {
    $(this).next('.togClass').hide(1000);
  }
});
```

Where you see `.next()` you'll actually need the appropriate jQuery traversal methods -- unlikely to be the one I've randomly assumed in the example.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Should do the trick.